# Use map() for functions that does not return a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a quick question:

If I have a function:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def f(x):
    return (x**2)
result = list(map(f, a))
print(result)
>>> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

but if I:

```
result = []
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def f(x):
    result.append(x**2)
map(f, a)
print(result)
>>> []
```

it won't work.

However, it will work if I write the function this way:

```
result = []
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def f(x):
    result.append(x**2)
for i in a:
    f(i)
print(result)
>>> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

even if I include a return value for it:

```
result = []
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def f(x):
    result.append(x**2)
    return x**2
map(f, a)
print(result)           # >>> []
print(list(map(f,a)))   # >>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Should I understand it as the map() must be applied on a function with a return value and return value only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` creates an iterator. It doesn't do the mapping immediately, it does it one by one *as you consume the iterator.* `list(map(...))` immediately consumes the entire iterator to turn it into a list. But in your tests where it doesn't work, you're never consuming the iterator, so `f` never gets called even once.

In other words: doesn't work:

```
map(f, a)
print(result)
```

Works:

```
list(map(f, a))  # ← list consumes the iterator
print(result)
```

Answer (score 11):

What you are seeing here is the effect of [lazy-evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Python 3 made most functions like this (`map`, `filter`, `zip` etc) work lazily where they used to work eagerly in Python 2, that is, instead of immediately returning and materializing a data-structure when you call `map(f, some_iterable)`, instead, `map` returns a map-object, which can then be iterated over to either materialize a data structure or work with the elements one-by-one (letting you work in a memory-efficient way).

```
>>> result = []
>>> m = map(lambda x: result.append(x), range(10))
>>> m
<map object at 0x10a0b7278>
>>> result
[]
>>> next(m)
>>> result
[0]
>>> next(m)
>>> result
[0, 1]
>>> list(m)
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> result
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

### However!

You should **not** be using `map` or `filter` or list-comprehensions for their side-effects. These are all functional constructs, and you should avoid mutating state when using them. It is simply bad style, and also, as you noticed when I called `list` on my map object, it creates and immediately discards a useless list of `None` (because functions that don't return anything implicitely return `None`).

So, to answer your question, yes you can use "map() for functions that does not return a value" but you **shouldn't**. Just use a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

With **Python 2** it will work...

I tried all of them and this is my result set:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

Comment: because you are on Python 2.

Comment: Ah I saw no Python 3 requirement :-)

Comment: Yes, for the record, I didn't downvote, but generally you should assume users are asking about Python 3 unless otherwise specified, or at least consider that possibility. Python 2 is already almost at it's end-of life date.

Comment: Will do next time thnx

Comment: You should edit your question and point out that this would work *in Python 2*, that is a good point that would merit an answer.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't mean to not mentioning python 3. It is just that I am a beginner that just started writing programss. Python 3 is my first language and I have never used python 2 before and didn't know that py2 does not have this problem